# PIG: Unable to open iterator for alias AliasName.Scalar has more than one row in the output

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, epoch

I am new to pig and trying to learn on my own.

I have written a script to get the epoch time with a word that is reading from words.txt file.

Here is the script.

```
words = LOAD 'words.txt' AS word:chararray;
B = FOREACH A GENERATE CONCAT(CONCAT(A.word,'_'),(chararray)ToUnixTime(CurrentTime());
dump B;
```

But the issue is, if words.txt file have only one word it is giving proper output.

If it is having multiple words like

```
word1
word2
word3
word4
```

then it is giving the following error

> ERROR 1066: **Unable to open iterator for alias B**
>
> java.lang.Exception:
>   org.apache.pig.backend.executionengine.ExecException: ERROR 0:
>   **Scalar has more than one row in the output. 1st : (word1 ), 2nd :(word2) (common cause: "JOIN" then "FOREACH ... GENERATE foo.bar"
>   should be "foo::bar" )** at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.runTasks(LocalJobRunner.java:462)
>   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.run(LocalJobRunner.java:522)
>   Caused by: org.apache.pig.backend.executionengine.ExecException: ERROR
>   0: Scalar has more than one row in the output. 1st : (word1 ), 2nd
>   :(word2) (common cause: "JOIN" then "FOREACH ... GENERATE foo.bar"
>   should be "foo::bar" ) at
>   org.apache.pig.impl.builtin.ReadScalars.exec(ReadScalars.java:122) at
>   o

Please suggest me to solve this issue.

Thank you.

Comment: got it.in script just removed A. it worked

Answer (score 1):

solved on my own.
just removed the A. from the inner CONCAT. It worked for me.

script:

```
words = LOAD 'words.txt' AS word:chararray;
B = FOREACH A GENERATE CONCAT(CONCAT(word,'_'),(chararray)ToUnixTime(CurrentTime());
dump B;
```